# Is it possible to have MathJax in a question?

Tags: discussion, support

In all other stack exchanges I use (Chemistry, Physics, Mathematics, etc.) I can just do $x$ and get x printed in a math-style font. In this question it didn't work:

[Is there a font where lower-case $x$ and $z$ look more like $X$ and $Z$, and how do I switch all my equations to have that font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509147/is-there-a-font-where-lower-case-x-and-z-look-more-like-x-and-z-and-how?noredirect=1#comment1287792_509147)

Is the syntax to get MathJax different in TeX stack exchange or do people here just not want math to be typeset by MathJax in questions here?

Comment: Thank you, I'll update my question.